# Javascript Modules Error in ASP.NET Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, es6-modules

I just tried to do up a quick sample app for modern ASP.NET development and the Javascript is being problematic. As soon as you encounter a library which is exposed as a module (e.g. "qs"), you hit a road-block.

Originally, my code looked like this, with just script tags added to the markup and it was working fine:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.24.0/axios.min.js"></script>
    @*<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qs/6.10.2/qs.min.js"></script>*@
    <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
    <script>
        main.msg = '@msg';
        main.bootVue();
        main.init();
    </script>
}
```

But then I added [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) and the following error ensued:

> "ReferenceError: qs is not defined"

**note:** captializing the Q does work (as in `Qs`)
Otherwise, I believe the issue is the fact that `qs` is exposed as a module.

I'd be keen to learn how I can change my code so that it uses the `qs` library as intended.

Do I need to introduce 3rd party tooling like Requirejs or Webpack so that the browser understands modules? Or is it possible to just do this simply with raw Javascript.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.24.0/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script type="module">
        import { main } from "./js/main.js"
            main.msg = '@msg';
        main.bootVue();
        main.init();
    </script>
}
```

And in `main.js`, there is this:

```
import { qs } from "../js/qs.min.js"
...
export const main = new Main();
```

But I get the following js error:

> The requested module '../js/qs.min.js' does not provide an export named 'qs'

Am I on the right track, or is there something I am not understanding?

The code using `qs` is:

```
sendDate: () => {
    axios.post('', qs.stringify({ selectedDate: this.getEpoch(this.selectedDate) }), {
            headers: {
            RequestVerificationToken: this.antiForg
            }}
    );
},
```

Comment: Hi,  what is your js code when you get the error:`"ReferenceError: qs is not defined"`?

Comment: @Rena Updated the question to show how `qs` is being used. It is in `main.js` on a button-click.

Comment: The https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qs/6.10.2/qs.min.js that you linked does not use  ES6 modules? It uses UMD, and defines a global `Qs` variable.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "*But then I added qs*". And `import { qs } from "../js/qs.min.js"` contains a relative import of a module you haven't shown.

Comment: @Bergi yeah sorry, that was meant to be `import { qs } from "qs"`. Yeah, I kinda figured out that the q is a capital, but [all of their doco](https://github.com/ljharb/qs) states that it is a small q. What do I look for to glean that it uses UMD and how does that affect the way you reference it in a script tag?

Comment: It doesn't affect the way you reference it in a script tag, it's just a script and should be included like you did originally. Given the library does not support ES modules yet, you will need to continue including it that way; and `import … from 'qs'` will either need to be omitted or handled by a build tool.